# Why seleniumwire gives an error OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('PEM routines', '', 'no start line')]?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm just creating a driver, but it gives me an error:

```
OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('PEM routines', '', 'no start line')].
```

Here is the code:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

why is that?

This error appears only when I use seleniumwire. When I use usual selenium, there is no such error.

Comment: I just run this code and have an error. I don't have more code, only this...

Comment: you can use the example from the official docs here:  https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire   . . . does this work for you ?

Comment: It gives me the same error